# Solved. Rank of a singular matrix after reducing its range?

Tags: matrix-rank

Suppose I have a linear system $Ax = b$. The matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ has $Rank(A) = n < m$, so it is a singular matrix. Suppose I separate the variables into three groups: $x_i, x_-$ and $x_+$.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}A_{ii}&A_{i+}&A_{i-}\\A_{+i}&A_{++}&A_{+-}\\A_{i-}&A_{+-}&A_{--} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_{i}\\x_{+}\\x_{-}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_{i}\\b_{+}\\b_{-}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Then I set some variables $x_+ = x_- $, which lead to the following reduced linear system:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}A_{ii}&A_{i-} + A_{i+} \\
A_{i-} + A_{+i}&A_{--} + A_{-+} + A_{+-} + A_{++} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_{i}\\x_{-}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_{i}\\b_{-} + b_{+}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

My question is, is there any relation between the singularities of the full system and the reduced one?

I'm facing the problem of a rigid body in dynamics. The stiffness matrix is singular and you have to restrict the 6 degrees of freedom related to translation and rotation. Here my $x$ belongs to the displacement vector, so with the equation $x_+ = x_-$ I'm setting some displacements to be equal to others.

Weird thing is that my **resultant system is full rank**, but it does not make sense in my problem since there is an infinite number of displacements which fulfills that restriction. I expect the rank to be $l-6 \leq n \lt l$ (with $l$ number of columns in reduced $A$), but not full rank.

Thank you for your time!

---

Solved the problem. The full rank was because of bad assembling of the reduced matrix. Answering the question:

> is there any relation between the singularities of the full system and the reduced one?

Yes, but the number of dependent rows can decrease. It depends on which variables are coupled.